# How to move folder and its contents to the parent folder?

Tags: windows-7, cut-and-paste

Is there a quick GUI way (without command line) to move a folder and all of its contents to the parent folder?

eg:

```
folder 1
   folder 2
      folder 3
      file 1
      file 2
```

Can I move `folder 3`, `file 1` and `file 2` to be another folder in `folder 1`?:

```
folder 1
    folder 2
    folder 3
    file 1
    file 2
```

I am basically looking for a quicker way to to the actions:

- select
- cut
- go to the parent folder
- paste

Comment: Umm... drag and drop?

Comment: That involves opening another window and going to the parent folder then, so basically the same thing as cut and paste

Comment: I suppose if you have the dumb window open that only has the single pane... normally you have the second pane on the left that shows the folder hierarchy so you can just drag from the right and drop on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Explorer,

- Go to the `folder 2` directory.
- Select all of its contents (or, at least, all that you want to move).
- Drag them to `folder 1` in the *navigation pane*<sup>1</sup> (the left pane) of the same window.

  [image]

Contrary to Enigma’s explanation, this does a move (not a copy), so you don’t even need to delete anything from `folder 2`.

---

<sup>1</sup>  If your Windows Explorer windows don’t have a navigation pane
(showing the folder tree), click “Organize” » “Layout” » “Navigation pane”. 
For more information, see [Working with the navigation pane](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/working-with-navigation-pane#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: I've never actually used the sidebar on the left to view the folder hierarchy - if I had, this would have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could drag `folder 3` onto `folder 1` in the explorer view and then just delete `folder 3`

2 actions instead of 4

Comment: Holding the `shift` key during the drag and drop will perform a move rather than a copy, so that's probably the way to go, rather than introducing a deletion step